# C++ multi-character character constant

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino

Using an arduino keypad to output a number on the 7 seg display. I am doing this using the robojax-Keypad library. The error it get is:
 `\7SegDisKeypad.ino:245:14: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]` I have checked to make sure all input values are correct. I am unsure why this is happening and not sure how I would go about fixing it.
This is my code: (With 7 seg display code taken out)

```
#include <Keypad.h>


int E = 13;
int D = 12;
int C = 11;
int DP = 10;
int B = 9;
int A = 8;
int F = 7;
int G = 6;

int k1 = A0;
int k2 = A1;
int k3 = A2;
int k4 = A3;
int k5 = 5;
int k6 = 4;
int k7 = 3;
int k8 = 2;

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {A0, A1, A2, A3}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {5,4,3,2}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

//7 Seg display code here

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(E, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DP, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(B, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(F, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(G, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key == 'k1') {
    one();
  }


}
```

This is my first time using this library and I am still fairly new with c++ and arduinos so any help is appreciated! 
Many thanks,
James

Comment: `  if (key == 'k1') {` this defines a character iso a string.

Comment: I think the warning is reasonably self explanatory? `'k1'` has more than one character but is a character constant which should have a single character only, presumably you mean't just `k1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're using [this keypad library](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Keypad/).

Then `keypad.getKey()` returns the actual *character* of the keypad, as initialized by `keys`.

So if you press the `5` key then `keypad.getKey()` would return the character `'5'`.